# Is there any way to drag and drop from a treeview to canvas in tkinter?

Tags: canvas, tkinter, frame

I have tried dragging and dropping from a canvas to another canvas, but now I need to drag from a frame and drop it on canvas, Is it possible in tkinter ?
I am really naive in tkinter .. :)

Comment: Being specific I need to drag from a treeview which is in a frame.

Comment: I just need to know is it possible or not, coz till now all drag and drops I have done were based on Canvas widget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible. Bind to `<ButtonPress-1>` on the `Treeview` to start, use the event information to get what was clicked on, and the do a binding on `<ButtonRelease-1>` to handle the drop.

You'll have to manage any sort of visual indication yourself. One solution is to use a `Toplevel` window, set the `overrideredirect` attribute, put something in the window (eg: the text being dragged), and then bind to `<B1-Motion>` to move the window as the user moves the mouse.

Comment: Thank you so much for this response, never expected you will be responding. Thanks again ... Now, the scenario...the below is working for me.
I am able to print the treeview's children on the canvas but that's easy.
What I am looking forward is to copy and paste kind of stuff to happen inside the same window and within two different widgets(i:e Treeview and canvas).
Have seen oval board example and all others of your they were a great learning.. (y)

Comment: @AnuragUpadhyaya Can you post some code that shows how you solved this?